# Common return type for all ANTLR visitor methods

Tags: antlr, visitor-pattern

I'm writing a parser for an old proprietary report specification with ANTLR and I'm currently trying to implement a visitor of the generated parse tree extending the autogenerated abstract visito class.

I have little experience both with ANTLR (which I learned only recently) and with the visitor pattern in general, but if I understood it correctly, the visitor should encapsulate ***one** single operation* on the whole data structure (in this case the parse tree), thus sharing the same return type between each `Visit*()` method.
Taking an example from The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference book by Terence Parr, to visit a parse tree generated by a grammar that parses a sequence of arithmetic expressions, it feels natural to choose the `int` return type, as each node of the tree is actually part of the the arithmetic operation that contributes to the final result by the calculator.

Considering my current situation, I don't have a common type: my grammar parses the whole document, which is actually split in different sections with different responsibilities (variable declarations, print options, actual text for the rows, etc...), and I can't find a common type between the result of the visit of so much different nodes, besides `object` of course.
I tried to think to some possible solutions:

1. I firstly tried implementing a stateless visitor using `object` as
   the common type, but the amount of type casts needed sounds like a
   big red flag to me. I was considering the usage of JSON, but I think
   the problem remains, potentially adding some extra overhead in the
   serialization process.
2. I was also thinking about splitting the visitor in more smaller
   visitors with a specific purpose (get all the variables, get all the
   rows, etc.), but with this solution for each visitor I would
   implement only a small subset of the method of the autogenerated
   interface (as it is meant to support the visit of the whole tree),
   because each visiting operation would probably focus only on a
   specific subtree. Is it normal?
3. Another possibility could be to redesign the data structure so that
   it could be used at every level of the tree or, better, define a generic
   specification of the nodes that can be used later to build the data
   structure. This solution sounds good, but I think it is difficult to
   apply in this domain.
4. A final option could be to switch to a stateful visitor, which
   incapsulates one or more builders for the different sections that
   each `Visit*()` method could use to build the data structure
   step-by-step. This solution seems to be clean and doable, but I have
   difficulties to think about how to scope the result of each visit
   operation in the parent scope when needed.

What solution is generally used to visit complex ANTLR parse trees?

Comment: Yes, the generated visitor class sets the return type for all visitor methods to a common type. So, if you are constructing an AST bottom-up using the visitor class, you have to pick a class on the type lattice that encompasses all possible types you could actually return, which usually defaults to "object", and lots of type casts. An alternative to think about is the generated listener with each parse node having a specific type and attributes that you evaluate bottom-up on the Exit() methods. Or, you could write your own visitor class, with different return types for each method.

Comment: The listener solution may be viable, I'll investigate it, thanks. About the type casts, I'm sorry to hear that it is a common solution: I know that unit tests should cover all possible type-related problems, but I still think it's a code smell that may lead to bugs. About implementing my own visitor, I already thought about that, but it fails to be useful when using the general `Visit()` method, which must return `object` to abstract away the choice of what actual `Visit*()` method to call. As visitor pattern is meant to be used with the general method, the casts would still be needed...

Comment: Option 2 is one I've used several times. I'd say it's pretty normal.

Comment: Is not a problem if a visitor actually implement only a bunch of the visit methods exposed (say 2 out of 50)?

Comment: Hi @NiccoMlt, facing the same issue here. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Hi, it passed some time from when I implemented that, but if I remember correctly because of time constraints I opted for a mixture of option 1 and 2: I implemented separate visitors for acceptably-large semantic areas, while I opted for using the object common type for the top-level visitor. Being able to define extension method that automated the casts and implementing very strict tests made it "less bad" to my eye.

Answer (score -1):

ANTLR4 parse trees are often complex because of recursion, e.g.
I would define the class ParsedDocumentModel whose properties would added or modified as your project evolves (which is normal, no program is set in stone).

Assuming your grammar be called Parser in the file Parser.g4, here is sample C# code:

```
public class ParsedDocumentModel {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    //other properties ...
}
public class ParserVisitor : ParserBaseVisitor<ParsedDocumentModel>
{
    public override ParsedDocumentModel VisitNounz(NounzContext context)
    {
        var res = "unknown";
        var s = context.GetText();
        if (s == "products")
            res = "<<products>>"; //for example

        var model = new ParsedDocumentModel();
        model.Title = res;  //add more info...
        return model;
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with you that implementing that generating an higher-level model from the parse tree is a good idea; it's exactly what I wanted to do. My question was about the visitor that I wanted to build to walk the tree and generate my model...